# Use of for loops for graphics in R

Tags: r, loops, mosaic-plot

I've got a table with different Plot Types and the Cluster number they are sorted by. The table looks like this:

```
'data.frame':   80 obs. of  16 variables:
 $ GS_CT_HC_NO: Factor w/ 16 levels "GS_CT_HC_NO",..: 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ CT_HC_NO   : Factor w/ 8 levels "CT_HC_NO","CT_HC_SW",..: 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ GS_CT_HC   : Factor w/ 8 levels "GS_CT_HC","GS_CT_LC",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ GS_HC_NO   : Factor w/ 8 levels "GS_HC_NO","GS_HC_SW",..: 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ GS_CT_NO   : Factor w/ 8 levels "GS_CT_NO","GS_CT_SW",..: 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ CT_HC      : Factor w/ 4 levels "CT_HC","CT_LC",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ CT_NO      : Factor w/ 4 levels "CT_NO","CT_SW",..: 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ GS_CT      : Factor w/ 4 levels "GS_CT","GS_FT",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ GS_HC      : Factor w/ 4 levels "GS_HC","GS_LC",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ GS_NO      : Factor w/ 4 levels "GS_NO","GS_SW",..: 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ HC_NO      : Factor w/ 4 levels "HC_NO","HC_SW",..: 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ NO         : Factor w/ 2 levels "NO","SW": 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ HC         : Factor w/ 2 levels "HC","LC": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ GS         : Factor w/ 2 levels "GS","SS": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ CT         : Factor w/ 2 levels "CT","FT": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ ClusterNr  : int  4 5 2 4 1 4 3 3 4 4 ...
```

Now, I created a Mosaicplot with the vcd package in R of GS_CT_HC_NO (first column) and the Cluster Nr with the following code:

```
mosaic(ClusterNr ~ GS_CT_HC_NO, data = groups, shade = TRUE, highlighting_fill = 
terrain.colors(5), labeling_args = list(tl_labels = FALSE, clip = FALSE, tl_varnames = TRUE,
pos_labels = "center", set_varnames = c(GS_CT_HC_NO = "Plot Class", ClusterNr = "Cluster"),
rot_labels = c(0, 0, 0, 90), gp_labels = (gpar(fontsize = 8)), just_labels = "left"))
```

I want to create such a plot for all other Plot Type combinations by using an for loop but when I tried with

```
for(j in 1:dim(groups[,-16])[2]) {

mosaic(ClusterNr ~ j, data = groups, shade = TRUE, highlighting_fill = 
terrain.colors(5), labeling_args = list(tl_labels = FALSE, clip = FALSE, tl_varnames =TRUE,
 pos_labels = "center", set_varnames = c(j = "Plot Class", ClusterNr = "Cluster"),
 rot_labels = c(0, 0, 0, 90), gp_labels = (gpar(fontsize = 8)), just_labels = "left"))

}
```

I received the Error:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = ~j + ClusterNr, data = groups) : 
 Variablenlängen sind unterschiedlich (gefunden für 'ClusterNr')
```

Last part of the error code means, that the length of variables is different (especially for the variable 'ClusterNr')

Is anybody please able to help me finding a correct working loop with the possibility to save every plot as a jpeg?

Cheers, Sven!

Comment: Please show the actual code you used that gave the error, and provide a [mcve]. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example.

Comment: Please show your implementation of *j* in `for` loop. And to be clear: do you want to subset your dataframe by *ClusterNr* and then run mosaic plots on each subset? *plot for all other Plot Type combinations* is not too clear.

Comment: The aim was to show the distribution of Plottypes in the Cluster groups. Therefore, i just want to plot the whole column of ClusterNr with each other column, which containing the Plottype combinations.